# TabBar and selecting the default TabBarItem

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

In my iphone application I put a UITabBar (not using UITabBarController)  in the bottom and put four TabBarItems(created IBoutlets -so that i'm able to track which item is selected), How can I set 1 TabBarItem is selected when the view is loaded (by  default).

Thanks in advance

Shinto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [selectedItem](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007521-CH3-SW7) property:

```
tabBar.selectedItem = defaultTabBarItem;
```